# Program getting stuck

Tags: c++

I have written a program for Round Robin Scheduling for CPU processes. The program was working fine before, but all of a sudden, the program stops working after several lines of code. I have tried to restart the Dev C++ app but the issue still persists. Is something wrong with my code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,n,time,remaining,temp,quantum_time;
    int wt=0,atat=0; //wt = Waiting Time, atat = Average Turn Around Time
    cout<<"Enter the number of processes to be scheduled"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    remaining=n;
    
    vector<int>at(n);
    vector<int>bt(n);
    vector<int>rt(n); //Dynamic array declaration using 'vector' library
    
    cout<<"Enter the Arrival Time and Burst Time for all the processes"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>at[i];
        cin>>bt[i];
        rt[i]=bt[i];
    }
    cout<<"Enter the Quantum Time:"<<endl;
    cin>>quantum_time;
    cout<<"\n\nProcess\t\t: Arrival Time\t:  Burst Time\t:  Turnaround Time  : Waiting Time\n\n";
    for(time=0,i=0;remaining!=0;)
    {
        if(rt[i]<=quantum_time&&rt[i]>0)
        {
            time+=rt[i];
            rt[i]=0;
            temp=1;
        }
        else if(rt[i]>0)
        {
            rt[i]-=quantum_time;
            time+=quantum_time;
        }
        if(rt[i]==0&&temp==1)
        {
            remaining--;
            printf("Process{%d}\t:\t%d\t:\t%d\t:\t %d\t    :\t   %d\n",i+1,at[i],bt[i],time-at[i],time-at[i]-bt[i]);
            cout<<endl;
            wt += time-at[i]-bt[i];
            atat += time-at[i];
            temp=0;
        }
        if(i==n-1)
            i=0;
        else if(at[i+1]<=time)
            i++;
        else
            i=0;
    }
    cout<<"Average Waiting Time: "<<wt*1.0/n<<endl;
    cout<<"Average TurnAround Time: "<<atat*1.0/n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to schedule 2 or more processes, the program gets stuck after displaying process 1

[image]

Comment: How do you know the program gets "stuck"? What does that mean? Your output is conditional, did you check that the conditions for entering the `if` where the output occurs are fulfilled? Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger? It should be easy to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong logic in the `for` iteration loop. The point is that your program iterates through this loop endlessly. After the first two loops, your entered data does not satisfy any condition, and `i` always resets to zero, so the program is constantly checking for the same unsuitable data.

Comment: So what exactly do I edit in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The changes I've made will fix the program's freeze. But I'm not sure that I was able to keep your logic correct. So, I changed the 'for' loop like this: `for (time = 0, i = 0; remaining > 0;)`, now we will be sure that the program will be able to complete.
Also, at the very end of the 'for' loop I put a `remaining--;` (approximately, line 55). I know that one of the conditions decreases this variable, but your program does not go into this condition every time.